# Map Onedrive for Business via Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, onedrive

I have this problem recently for creating Onedrive for Business as a desktop.lnk from a URL:

```
$user = [Environment]::UserName
$domain = "contoso.com"; # your Federated domain
$urldomain = "_contoso_com"
$mappath = "\\contoso-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\" + $user + $urldomain + "\Documents"
$iepath = "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
$sharepoint = "https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com"

#$ie.visible = $true #Uncomment this for debugging
Start-Process -FilePath $iepath -ArgumentList $sharepoint -WindowStyle Minimized
sleep -seconds 12 # give plenty of time to redirect
NET USE P: $mappath /PERSISTENT:YES
sleep -seconds 5
$targetpath = Get-Item("\\contoso-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\" + $user + $urldomain + "\Documents")
$Wshshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$shortcut = $Wshshell.CreateShortcut("$home\Desktop\Onedrive.lnk")
$shortcut.TargetPath = $targetpath.FullName
$shortcut.Save()
#Stop-Process -Name iexplore
```

In this case, It will create a .lnk, but the .lnk cannot direct me to this network drive. In other words, the .lnk is broken as I map them on the domain network. (It's the same thing for all Windows 8 and Windows 10 computer)

However, I cannot figure out how to let user who is not in the domain still run this script and be able to map their Onedrive from their personal laptop without going though "My Computer" and "Map as a Network Drive" all those stuff.

Thanks for the help